# Server name for SQL Server Management Studio 17.1

Tags: sql-server, ssms

How do I find the server name for "SQL Server Management Studio 17.1", downloaded at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this. The server name is the server you're trying to connect to. Management Studio doesn't have a server. But in any case this is probably off topic on Stack Overflow since it's not about programming.

Comment: SSMS is client tool. You have to install SQL Server (Express, Developer) instance or connect to existing instance.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-ssms) to know what SQL Server Management Studio is:

> SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) is an integrated environment for managing any SQL infrastructure. Use SSMS to access, configure, manage, administer, and develop all components of SQL Server, Azure SQL Database, and SQL Data Warehouse. SSMS provides a single comprehensive utility that combines a broad group of graphical tools with a number of rich script editors to provide access to SQL Server for developers and database administrators [...].

You are confusing the management studio with an effective database engine. You use the management studio to connect to one or more SQL Server databases. At that point, you can then *access, configure, manage, administer, and develop all components* of a SQL Server database.

---

Suppose you have SSMS and connect to a SQL Server instance. You can then query a database on the SQL Server instance with ad-hoc queries. One such query could be

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME
```

which would return the [server name of the SQL Server instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/servername-transact-sql).